# Spring 3 init map in bean

Tags: java, spring

I have following beans setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="SMTPPlugin" class="com.org.proj.plugins.SMTPPlugin" />

    <bean id="AnotherPlugin" class="com.org.proj.plugins.export.AnotherPlugin" />

    <bean id="PluginBaseService" class="com.proj.plugins.PluginBaseService">
        <property name="plugins">
             <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.proj.common.plugins.interfaces.IPluginBase">              
                <entry key="SMTP" value-ref="SMTPPlugin" />
                <entry key="ANOTHER" value-ref="AnotherPlugin" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Inside PluginBaseService I have map of String, IPluginBase and I want to inject beans SMTPPlugin and AnotherPlugin in there. Both are implement IPluginBase interface. However I'm getting following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [com.org.proj.plugins.SMTPPlugin] to required type [com.proj.common.plugins.interfaces.IPluginBase] for property 'plugins[SMTP]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

Should I really have some converter in order to make this work or how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Apparently you aren't implementing the interface you are expected to implement.

Comment: As it stated in my message. Both beans implement interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a public default constructor in SMTPPlugin.